# ssl_requirement failing on production only and only on two pages

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ssl

I've got a Rails 3.2 app where I'm trying to debug a weird ssl problem.

I'm page caching throughout my app and to maintain dynamic content I am making ajax requests to update certain aspects.

All of the pages that are cached are supposed to be requested by http only.  All but two of them are redirecting to http when an ssl request is made.

The problem is, that these two pages [Artists](https://www.artsicle.com/artists) and the [Blog](https://www.artsicle.com/blog) are failing to redirect back to http and the ajax requests to refresh content is getting canceled.  To the best of my knowledge, it is getting canceled because it sees normal http as a different site and you can't make ajax requests to a different site under ssl.

Setting up a local signed certificate has not helped.  In development these two pages are acting appropriately.  I'm also using AWS ELB where the ssl terminates at the load balancer and goes to port 80 and that seems to also be working appropriately.

I could force just these two pages to redirect to http every time but I much rather get to the bottom of this.

I am using ssl_requirement to do the app level redirects.

I'm looking for ideas of how this could be happening.  I've combed my codebase and I can't find anything at the app level that would be making this happen.  I don't think my apache vhost is perfect but there's nothing pertaining to just these two pages.  Anyone got a clue of where in the stack this could be occurring?

Edit:

Finally realized that since the pages are fully cached, the request is only hitting apache and never the application where it would get redirected. This makes me question why the Ajax requests are getting canceled. The Ajax requests are to the same domain but not encrypted. Shouldn't that just show up as a warning of 'insecure content'?  I'm using jquery getScript to load the dynamic content.

Answer (score 0):

Well, this will go down in the history of stupid mistakes but I thought I'd leave it up to help others googling.

The simple answer is that my ajax calls were not being allowed over an ssl connection.  If your ssl_requirement has the method ssl_allowed, make sure that the ajax method your calling to load the dynamic content is allowed over ssl.  Otherwise the request will be canceled or it will get a 302 redirect.